# 2 Similar Queries Run at Vastly Different Speed in a Very Surprising Way

Tags: spatial-database, query

I have to be very careful here. Both queries are so similar that the only different is the area searched.

What's surprising is the query that run on **BIGGER AREA**, and naturally yield **MORE ROWS**, is the one that run way **FASTER**.

In fact the only reason why I want to run the second query is to narrow down the search because the original query returns too many results.

```
SELECT BusinessID
FROM tableauxiliary
WHERE MBRWithin( Latlong, GeomFromText( 'MULTIPOINT(-6.2209869856406 106.73701301436,-6.1490130143594 106.80898698564)' ) )
AND MATCH (
FullTextSearch
)
AGAINST (
'res*'
IN BOOLEAN
MODE
)
```

returns

> Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 5,007 total, Query took 0.0226 sec)

Now my code will streamline things up.

I asked the same query except for SMALLER regions

```
SELECT BusinessID
FROM
  tableauxiliary
WHERE
  MBRContains(
        GeomFromText (
            'MULTIPOINT(-6.1928749092968 106.7651250907,-6.1771250907032 106.7808749093)'
            ),
            Latlong)    
  AND MATCH (FullTextSearch) AGAINST ('res*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND Prominent >15
```

> Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 30 total, Query took 15.3889 sec)

What gives?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: It looks to me like it is MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell with out seeing the data and an *explanation* of the query but one uses contains and the other within - may be those are implemented differently on your system (knowing that might also help answers).

Comment: Sorry they both use the same thing at first but I tweaked that. No that is not the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your fulltext index is not used in the second query. An error of the optimization algorithm choosing the wrong path. BTW: you should add which database you are using (MySQL?), this is important information. Eg MySQL spatial support is still limited.

Comment: I used mysql. The problem is the fact that the spatial part need to be executed first. However, the optimization algorithm execute the less restrictive full text search first.